# Wikipedia API for geolocations

Tags: geolocation, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Is it possible, using the existing Wikipedia API's to get a list of articles around a Geo-location? Sort of like how Google maps does it?

I would like to say that I am "here" and find out what is around me on Wikipedia.

I can see on articles like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queens_Park%2C_Moonee_Ponds) you can see the "Coordinates" on the right hand side, so I would like to do a query on these coordinates...

any thoughts?

Comment: You might even be able to use Google maps's API to get results from their Wikipedia layer.

Comment: just found this: http://www.geonames.org/export/wikipedia-webservice.html#findNearbyWikipedia which might help me out...

Comment: @BennyJobigan Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use [DBpedia](https://wiki.dbpedia.org/about).
Sample page with "lat" and "lon" data [extracted](https://dbpedia.org/page/Cambridge).
And it can be queried with [SPARQL](https://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess).

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that project even existed! Thanks Ill take a good look at it :)

Comment: @jpatokal: how to use dbpedia to solve the problems OP posted? can u shed some light on this?

Comment: Nowadays, this is implemented in query.wikidata.org.

Answer (score 27):

**UPDATED ANSWER**:
[Wikilocation](http://bendodson.com/weblog/2014/08/19/retiring-tubeupdates-and-wikilocation/) has been retired and now there is an [**OFFICIAL WIKIPEDIA API**](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoData#API)

```
? action=query
& list=geosearch
& gsradius=<radius-in-meters>
& gscoord=<lat>|<lon>
```

**[HTML example](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gscoord=37.786971|-122.399677) | [JSON Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gscoord=37.786971|-122.399677&format=json)**

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at [Wikilocation](http://wikilocation.org/), might be useful.

Comment: UPDATE: Wikilocation has been retired and now there is an [OFFICIAL WIKIPEDIA API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoData#API)

Answer (score 10):

This is nowadays built into Wikipedia through Special:Nearby.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Nearby

Answer (score 5):

It seems like there is no Wikipedia API for this, but [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aWikiProject_Geographical_coordinates#Tools_and_applications_based_on_coordinates_from_Wikipedia) describes how others make use of this information:

> All coordinates are available for
>   download in Wikipedia database dumps.
>   To get the coordinates from the XML
>   format dump of all articles
>   (enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2,
>   4 GB), the dump needs to be parsed for
>   pages containing coordinates in the
>   entry formats listed above. Most
>   articles in Wikipedia conform to these
>   formats and coordinates are easy to
>   parse from the wikitext with regular
>   expressions for simple character
>   sequences. As all coordinates link to
>   the same PHP tool, they may also be
>   found from the SQL format table of
>   external links
>   (enwiki-latest-externallinks.sql.gz,
>   725MB). This second method will
>   however not include all available
>   information about the coordinates,
>   such as their position between the
>   article body and the title area.

Comment: Thanks Philipp, I did manage to get some DB dumps, its a pity that you have to go down this path. But like I commented, I might just use the http://www.geonames.org/export/wikipedia-webservice.html#findNearbyWikipedia service for now...

Comment: The coordinates are actually pretty time consuming to parse as they come in few different formats. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Coord for more details about the formats.

Answer (score 5):

Solution jquery and geonames API:

a,b = longitude, latitude, tweet -> html div

```
function getcontent(a,b) {
    jQuery(function($) {
        $.getJSON('http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyWikipediaJSON?formatted=true&lat='+ a +'&lng='+ b +'&username=username&style=full&lang=de&wikipediaUrl&thumbnailImg', function(json) {
            for(var i = 0; i < json.geonames.length; i++) {
                $("#tweet").prepend('<span style="font-family: geneva, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"><br><br><img src="wikilogo.gif"><br>' + json.geonames[i].summary + '<br><a href="http://'+ json.geonames[i].wikipediaUrl +'" target="_blank">'+ json.geonames[i].wikipediaUrl +'</a><br></span>');
            }
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know, this is an old question, but here is the URL format for a similar query:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&format=json&gscoord=40.418670|-3.699389&gsradius=10000&gslimit=10

after `&gscoord=` you should put the coordinates separated by `|`, and after `&gsradius=` the search radius in meters, gslimit is the max number of entries in response.

The response contains JSON.

Answer (score 1):

DBpedia and SPARQL are not good options, at least not for the German Wikipedia: The coverage is too small.

I'm trying to parse all the different geo coordinate formats by myself right now (from the dumps), but that's quite difficult as there are really a lot of different variants.